# I'm new in PHP and I'm getting this error:

Tags: php, mysql

> Notice: Use of undefined constant msg - assumed 'msg' in C:\wamp\www\Stanly 1 - Copy\index.php on line 48
>   Log In
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant msg - assumed 'msg' in C:\wamp\www\Stanly 1 - Copy\index.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant msg - assumed 'msg' in C:\wamp\www\Stanly 1 - Copy\index.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant msg - assumed 'msg' in C:\wamp\www\Stanly 1 - Copy\index.php on line 50

I couldn't find any solution online, so maybe someone can help me.

Here is the code:

```
if($_GET[msg] != ""){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:#FF0000;" align="center"><?php if ($_GET[msg] == 1) {
    echo "Login failed.";
} elseif ($_GET[msg] == 2) {
    echo "Only Administrator allowed.";
} elseif ($_GET[msg] == 3) {
    echo "You have logged out.";
} ?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="120" class="style23">Username</td>
        <td width="164" class="style19">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style23">Password</td>
        <td class="style19">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style19" colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I do after that (or at least I'm trying) is to update a table in MySQL.

Thank you for taking your time to answer me. Cheers!

Comment: The code is missing

Comment: Please post your code from lines 40-60 from inside the index.php file located in your Stanly 1 - Copy directory, I am sure we should be able to find the answer there.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network. To get more out of question-and-answer site, I'd advise reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JonSurrell the code was missing when the question was sent, maybe he edited when you looked at it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is an unquoted string.

```
$_GET[msg]
```

should be

```
$_GET['msg']
```

Because you have left this unquoted, PHP tries to find a constant `msg`, cannot, and interprets it as a string, which is what you wanted in the first place.

As long as there is no constant defined `msg`, your code will show that notice, but function as you expected.

Your code becomes:

```
if($_GET['msg'] != ""){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="color:#FF0000;" align="center"><?php if($_GET['msg'] == 1){ echo "Login failed."; } elseif($_GET['msg'] == 2){ echo "Only Administrator allowed."; }elseif($_GET['msg'] == 3){ echo "You have logged out."; }?> </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
  <td width="120" class="style23">Username</td>
  <td width="164" class="style19">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="style23">Password</td>
  <td class="style19">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="style19" colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;
   <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Its funny how easy things are missed, I was looking at his code a second ago scratching my head and then start hitting my head after noticing the missing quotes, You answered before I could so Kudo's...